# In Spring Boot, how do you build a JAR file for a different profile even if proper environment variables have not been set?

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Boot, so bear with me. Currently, I'm working on a small app just for the purposes of learning Spring Boot. My goal is to deploy it using AWS (elastic beanstalk).

So far, I've created three application properties files:

- application.properties: Properties which apply to all profiles.
- application-dev.properties: Properties only for development. This includes localhost connection to DB, path to self signed key store, etc.
- application-prod.properties: Properties used only for prod. This includes the prod DB details, etc.

Everything works fine when running the app locally using the dev profile since everything has been hard coded in the application-dev.properties.

However, the application-prod.properties file contains references which will be resolved through OS environment variables, such as:

```
spring.datasource.username=${DB_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password=${DB_PASSWORD}
```

I currently do not have the variables `DB_USERNAME` and `DB_PASSWORD` set up in my local OS, and I do not wish to do so. But when I run the following command, it obviously fails:

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage -Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

It fails because it's unable to find the above environment variables.

Is there any way to delay this check until I actually execute the JAR? My plan is to build the JAR locally and then copy it over to my prod server, and run it there. The prod server will definitely have these environment variables.

The workaround I found is this:

```
mvn package spring-boot:repackage -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
java -jar -Dspring.profiles.active=prod [jar-file-name].jar
```

However, this feels like a hack. And it may cause issues in the future that I can't think of right now.

Comment: What is maven doing when it fails? Is it running your integration tests? If so then you can build without setting a profile on the command line and use the `properties` field of the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to set up test profile properties.

Comment: @AndyBrown It's not failing because of the tests. It's not able to initialize at all as it is complaining about not being able to resolve `DB_USERNAME`.

Comment: OK, weird. I use gradle and its spring-boot plugins. These do not attempt to introspect your property files (I have dozens of properties set up like yours). They just compile and package. Maybe a maven expert can help you.

Comment: Your understanding of the profiles is bit off. You don't need to build a jar with `mvn package spring-boot:repackage -Dspring.profiles.active=prod`. Your workaround isn't a workaround it is the way it is supposed to work. You don't build a jar for an environment you build a jar which can be deployed in ANY environment... The profile you specify when building is the profile used to run the tests for instance it is't the profile that will be backed into your application.

Comment: @M.Deinum I see. I refactored by properties to make sure it gets built without any profiles, and then I specify the proper profile when running the JAR. So basically, I had to fix up the way I set up my properties. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use any value you want in those properties for prod profile. If the env varieble exists, Spring will take the value from there instead of the properties.

As explained [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html):

> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> [...]
>
> 10. OS environment variables.
>
> [...]
>
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants).

So your `application-prod.properties` can look like this:

```
spring.datasource.username=willBeOverridenByEnvValue
spring.datasource.password=willBeOverridenByEnvValue
```

You have to make sure though that you set both `SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME` and `SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD` env values in your prod server